# Database Design ManyToMany, OneToMany, ManyToOne, Django model

Tags: django-models, database-schema

I am confused as far as Database design goes for a Django application with specific relationships. I have been looking at the following database schema : http://www.databaseanswers.org/data%5Fmodels/customers_and_orders/index.htm

I am confused about the relationships between Customer_addresses and Customers, and Addresses.

I know that:

- one customer can have Many addresses.
- many customers can have the same (one) address

Does this equate to a many to many relationship?

- Many customers can have many addresses?

When I'm building the model in django I have (simplified):

```
class Customer_Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ManyToManyField('inventory.Customer')
    address = models.ManyToManyField('inventory.Address')
```

Is this right? or does this make more sense:

```
class Customer_Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKeyField('inventory.Customer')
    address = models.ManyToManyField('inventory.Address')
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

Based on the idea that it is a many to many relationship.
Does one ManyToMany relation, require two ManyToManyFields?

Based on the following:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29

Since Django supports ManyToManyFields, do I not even require the junction table?
And if I do use the junction table (Customer_addresses) the article seems to imply using Two OneToMany relationships, which wouldn't that just be two foreign keys like this?

```
class Customer_Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKeyField('inventory.Customer')
    address = models.ForgeinKeyField('inventory.Address')
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

Now that we know that Django builds the intermediate table, and the table Customer_Addresses  is not required. Which table should have the ManyToManyfield? the customer tables? or the Address table?

Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

In the Person/Groups examples.. The Groups has the ManyToManyField. Is there any reason the ManyToManyfield couldn't be defined in the Person table?

Comment: If in your case many customers can have the same address than its a manyToMany relationship.

Comment: So the first model would be the way to go?

Comment: Yes, the first will work for you. Risk of being presumptuous, I think you need to revise on your database basics, please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have read that, I guess the thing that confuses me about that is the last statement regarding ManyToManyFields. Since Django allows the use of ManyToManyfields.. do I not need the junction table? I'm going to update my question.

Comment: I am really sorry for missing that part out. It is a really good question actually. No you do not require two ManyToManyFields, Django backend handles everything https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: Now I think I understand the documents better. I don't need the junction table at all unless I want to add more fields to the junction table for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Thank you! If you want to sum this up in answer, I will accept it. Or I could do it and accept it after the two-day time limit.

Comment: I think you are getting the hang of django now, Best of luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### To Sum up

**For the first question.**

When a relationship states that

- one customer can have Many addresses.
- many customers can have the same (one) address

Than its clearly a Many-to-Many relationship and always use **ManyToManyField**

**Now for the second question.**

What if you want to have a intermediate table which has extra fields between two many to many entities(Tables/models)

Than create a new Model which has a ForiegnKey from the other two models. As in

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

For more [Read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Comment: Is there a paticular reason why the Group model gets the ManyToMany field. Why not have groups = models.ManyToManyfield(Group, through='Membership'). Would that change anything?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that I don't have sufficient points to reply to comments. So, to answer your question [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894663/database-design-manytomany-onetomany-manytoone-django-model#comment19145276_13895159): there is effectively no difference. As [the example in the Django documentation shows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), you are able to query the set of Groups to which a Person belongs as well as the set of Persons that belong to a Group:

```
>>> ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")
>>> paul = Person.objects.create(name="Paul McCartney")
>>> beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason= "Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all() # Get all Persons of a Group here
[<Person: Ringo Starr>]
>>> ringo.group_set.all() # Get all Groups for a Person here
[<Group: The Beatles>]
>>> m2 = Membership.objects.create(person=paul, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1960, 8, 1),
...     invite_reason= "Wanted to form a band.")
>>> beatles.members.all()
[<Person: Ringo Starr>, <Person: Paul McCartney>]
```